# Sencha Touch 2 App FieldSet not rendering

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am developing Sencha Touch 2 app, using the sdk version Sencha-touch-gpl 2.2.1. I am facing a very peculiar issue, I have a navigation view, in which the first view is a List Screen on itemdisclosure of individual item in the list the Detail Screen is displayed. The Detail screen comprises of fieldset & another list within a panel.

[image: List Screen]
[image: Detail Screen]

Until yesterday the app was working perfectly fine. Now I am facing an issue,

1) The toolbar Title is now not getting displayed, it shows for fraction of secs and then disappears (No code change is done and it was working perfectly fine a day before).

[image: toolbarissue]

2)The List screen displays properly, on itemDisclosure, in the detail screen the FieldSet is not getting displayed but the list in the detail screen is getting displayed perfectly fine. 
[image: DetailScreenwithissue]

I was populating the Detail screen with the record from the selected list item, I use the following code on itemdisclosure

showDetail : function(list, record) {
        this.getMain().push({
            xtype : 'ticketdetail',
            data : record,
        });

record holds the value, I have checked it via printing the ticketid on Console.

I have tried the following things,

1. Cleared browser cache
2. Generated another workspace, copied the project and run the project from there.
3. Used older version of the code in which these issues were not there

NONE OF Them worked :(

Has anyone faced this kind of issue or anyone has any suggestion. Please help!

Regards,
P

Comment: Something must have changed, code doesn't just suddenly break. Did you update to a new browser version?

Comment: Well I dint change anything, I also tried to make an older version of the application work but no luck there.

Comment: I said something must have changed, if not the code, then it's likely that the environment (browser) did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the problem caused by the auto-update to Chrome 29.  See the fix here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?f=90&a=43

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am fairly new to Sencha Touch, I changed the SCSS file under the mentioned path and in CMD prompt gave the "compass compile" command but got the following error.
C:\b6a-1f-437\Priya\Workspaces\UI5 Workspace\touch\resources\themes\stylesheets\
sencha-touch\base\mixins>compass compile
Compass can't find any Sass files to compile.
Is your compass configuration correct?.
If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argumen
t.
Run "compass -h" to get help.

Comment: Make sure you run `compass compile` from `resources\sass` as your working directory.