# Sencha controls override issue

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am new in sencha touch. I make a login page in there some override controls issue.
    Here is my code.

```
Ext.define('RaceNote.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: "widget.loginview",
    requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.form.Password', 'Ext.Label'],

    config: {
        title: 'Login',
        scrollable: 'false',
        layout: 'vbox',

        items: [

        {
            xtype: 'label',
            html: 'Login failed. Please enter the correct credentials.',
            itemId: 'signInFailedLabel',
            hidden: true,
            hideAnimation: 'fadeOut',
            showAnimation: 'fadeIn',
            style: 'color:#990000;margin:5px 0px;'
        }, {


            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Login Example',

            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                placeHolder: 'Username',
                itemId: 'userNameTextField',
                name: 'userNameTextField',
                required: true
            }, {
                xtype: 'passwordfield',
                placeHolder: 'Password',
                itemId: 'passwordTextField',
                name: 'passwordTextField',
                required: true
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'logInButton',
            ui: 'action',
            padding: '10px',
            text: 'Log In',

            listeners: [{
                delegate: '#logInButton',
                event: 'tap',
                fn: 'onLogInButtonTap'
            }]
        }]


    }
});
```

and it s looking below.
[image]

Comment: How is the panel being added to the Viewport?

Comment: @kevhender:launch: function () {

        Ext.Viewport.add([
            { xtype: 'loginview' }
        ]);

Comment: What version of ST are you using?  I'm able to see this fine in this fiddle: http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/LdICc/

Comment: i am using sencha touch 2 version

Comment: What is the full version? 2.?

Comment: @kevhender:and i am using chrome in mac for see output

Comment: now its ok in safari but in chrome still same issue i am using 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I'd say you are having the recent issue found with ST 2.2.1 and Chrome 29.  See my answer regarding this here: [Sencha Touch 2 App FieldSet not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442534/sencha-touch-2-app-fieldset-not-rendering/18442761#18442761)